# Let $G$ be a graph on n vertices and $\beta(G)$ denote the minimum size of a vertex cover of $G$. Show that $\beta(G) = n-1$ if and only if $G=K_n$.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph on n vertices and $\beta(G)$ denote the minimum size of a vertex cover of $G$. Show that $\beta(G) = n-1$ if and only if $G=K_n$.

I don't have any idea about where to start! I can see that this holds for $K_3$ and $K_4$ but I cannot think about how to prove it.

For the forward direction, I was about to say if $B(G)=n-1$ and we remove all of the edges in the vertex cover... but I don't know how to continue! With the backward direction, I am more at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G=K_n$ and we pick $m\le n-2$ vertices $v_1,\ldots, v_m$, there are two vertices $u,w$ we do not pick. The edge $uw$ then is not covered by our $m$ vertices. Hence $\beta(K_n)\ge n-1$. On the other hand, picking all but one vertex in $K_n$ clearly covers $K_n$.

Now let $G$ be an incomplete graph, say there is no edge $uw$. Then picking all vertices except $u,w$, we have obtained a vertex cover with $n-2$ vertices.